# Aligning text to bottom of label

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have several labels with a height of 3em. I'd like to align the text to the bottom of each label, such that a label with one line of text would have the text appear at the bottom of the label, while a label with two lines would have the second line appear at the bottom of the label.

For context, I have several columns in a Bootstrap row, each of which contains a label and a textarea. Some of the labels have longer text than others, which results in them taking up two lines of text when the width of the page is made smaller. I also set the height of each of the labels to 3em in order to prevent the textareas from appearing at different heights. However, I would like the text of the shorter labels to align with the bottom row of the longer labels (regardless of whether the longer labels are currently taking up one or two rows).

Example:

```
            <div class="row bottom-row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 textarea-div">
                    <label for="textArea1" class="titleLabel textareaLabel">Short</label>
                    <textarea id="textArea1"></textarea>

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 textarea-div">
                    <label for="textArea2" class="titleLabel textareaLabel">Short</label>
                    <textarea id="textArea2"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 textarea-div">
                    <label for="textArea3" class="titleLabel textareaLabel">A longer label</label>
                    <textarea id="textArea3"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 textarea-div">
                    <label for="textArea4" class="titleLabel textareaLabel">A longer label</label>
                    <textarea id="textArea4"></textarea>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by putting the text in a span and using flex to align the span to the bottom of the label which will need to have display: flex. The simplest approach is `margin-top:auto` on the span in the label that has display: flex, or using `justify-content: flex-end` to force the spans to the bottom of the labels.

EDIT: Spans removed following feedback. THX

```css
.row {
  margin: 0 -15px
}

.col-lg-3 {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px
}

.titleLabel {
  height: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end
}
```

```html
<div class="row bottom-row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 textarea-div">
          <label for="textArea1" class="titleLabel textareaLabel">A short one line label</label>
          <textarea id="textArea1"></textarea>

      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 textarea-div">
          <label for="textArea3" class="titleLabel textareaLabel">A longer label with at least two lines</label>
          <textarea id="textArea3"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 textarea-div">
          <label for="textArea4" class="titleLabel textareaLabel">A longer label with enough text to run over three lines and will be very long</label>
          <textarea id="textArea4"></textarea>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked - though I didn't have to use the span. Can you explain why that's necessary?

Comment: its not necessary if it works without it - my thinking was only that you are focing the entire text to the bottom of the label - but keep it without the spans if that works :) - thanks. EDIT - I have removed the spans as you have suggested - cleaner to not have them if they are not needed - thanks.